# Is there any way to select all the column, except particular column in psql?

Tags: psql

I have a table which contains 250 columns.
But I need to `select` 248 columns, `except two` columns.
How could I did it in PostgreSQL?
I need to do this without creating any temporary table.
Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: no. there's no `select * except foo,bar`-type syntax in sql. you either grab everything, or explicitly list what you do want.

Comment: But how could I explicitly list 248 columns

Comment: put fingers on keyboard, start pushing buttons... of course, you could usedynamic sql to query DB metadata, get the field list, and build a query excluding those two, but either way, you're building/writing a query that lists all 248 columns.